# Use of **per capita / head**

Tags: grammar, idioms-in-context

I keep on hearing phrases such as **doctors per capita** and **deaths per head of population** which make no sense to me, as I understand both **capita** and **head** (which derives from the Latin **caput**) to be singular. Am I alone in my doubts?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure capita is singular and not the plural of caput? Perhaps I am mistaken here but it looks like the plural of a neuter noun.

Comment: This is Wikipedia's explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per_capita, and seems to me to be saying **per person**

Comment: https://quizlet.com/162049481/latin-neuter-nouns-flash-cards/ suggests otherwise. Note also that the alternative to per capita is per stirpes which is also plural.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is that the most familiar uses in English are per followed by a singular noun. So we say miles per hour, kilometres per litre, parts per million. So we say per head too. Latin was different and in inheritance law we have *per capita* where each person gets an equal share versus *per stirpes* where each branch of the family gets an equal share. Both nouns are plural.

Answer (score 0):

Per takes the accusative; capita is the accusative plural of caput (noun, "head"). I would understand *per capita* as 'by heads'.

**Capita, capitis**
third declension

| Case | Singular | Plural |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nominative | caput | capita |
| Genitive | capitis | capitum |
| Dative | capiti | capitibus |
| Accusative | caput | capita |
| Ablative | capite | capitibus |
| Vocative | caput | capita |

Comment: This answers the Latin question (capita is a plural) but not the English (is singular or plural used in "per" expressions)

Answer (score 0):

In English the singular is used

> There are about 30 sheep per person.

> There are 0.001 deaths per head of population.

In Latin it is an idiom "by heads" and so in idioms borrowed from Latin, the Latin plural is used.  As it is an idiom the question of whether "capita" is singular or plural never occured to me.  It is just a phrase "per capita". Logically it should be "per caput" but logic doesn't help learn English (much).

> There are 0.001 deaths per capita.

Comment: I can figure 30 sheep per person but I can't figure 30 doctors per person!

Comment: But I understand 0.1 doctors per capita (10% of the population)